# Successively removing predictor variable from formula

Tags: r, nlme

I have a model formula in the form of

```
model.all <- lme(Response ~ A + B + C)
```

I would like to update this model by successively removing a predictor variable from the model, so I would end up with 3 models, specifically:

```
mod.1 <- lme(Response ~ B + C) ; mod.2 <- lme(Response ~ A + C) ; mod.3 <- lme(Response ~ A + B)
```

I am thinking of a loop function, so I am aware of the `update` function, but I have too many predictor variables to manually change the code.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for `?drop1`

Comment: Something similar. But one that works with `nlme` class objects. I get the error  `Error in extractAIC.lme(object, scale, k = k, ...) : 
  AIC undefined for REML fit`

Comment: My apologies, I would still need the results from each model (mod.1,2,3) to use as the raw data for a function in a different package.

Comment: ah ok, you want all results - i took a guess that you were doing model selection.

Comment: Yes I need all the results to calculate the marginal R2. Not interested in model selection as I already have my parsimonious model

Comment: Look at the very last line of help("formula"). It will help you not write all predictors by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `combn` in this occasion, see the example below:

**Example Data**

```
Response <- runif(100)
A <- runif(100)
B <- runif(100)
C <- runif(100)
```

**Solution**

```
a <- c('A','B','C')  #the names of your variables
b <- as.data.frame(combn(a,2)) #two-way combinations of those using combn

#create the formula for each model
my_forms <- sapply(b, function(x)   paste('Response ~ ', paste(x,collapse=' + '))) 

> my_forms #the formulas that will be used in the model
                 V1                  V2                  V3 
"Response ~  A + B" "Response ~  A + C" "Response ~  B + C" 

#run each model
my_models <- lapply(my_forms, function(x)  lm(as.formula(x)))
```

**Output**

```
> summary(my_models[[1]])

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(x))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.48146 -0.20745 -0.00247  0.24263  0.58341 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.32415    0.08232   3.938 0.000155 ***
A            0.25404    0.09890   2.569 0.011733 *  
B            0.07955    0.10129   0.785 0.434141    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2828 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06507,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04579 
F-statistic: 3.375 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 0.03827
```

As you can see each model is saved in as a list element in `my_models`. I find this quite easy to make and run.